# X-axis value increments automatically when first point plotted is at (0,0) using C# Chart API

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I'm trying to use the C# Charting API for the first time and am having some problems.  I have two hardware signals that I want to plot on a graph that has an x-axis that goes from -10 to 10 and a y-axis also from -10 to 10.  I'm using the SeriesChartType.Point chart type for this and in all but one case the code works the way I expect.  I'm adding points to the chart by using the AddXY function.  In reality the values are coming from hardware but for this example I simply hard coded the values.

The problem I'm having is that if the very first point to be plotted has an x-axis value of 0 the chart seems to ignore the 0 and simply increment the x-axis value by one for each subsequent point that is plotted.

I created the following simplified example to demonstrate my problem.  I hard coded my x-axis value as 0 and my y-axis value at 2.  When it plots points the first point is plotted at (1,2), the next at (2,2), then (3,2), (4,2) and finally (5,2).

I should note that this only happens if the very first point to be plotted has an x-axis value of 0, if it has ANY other value the chart will function correctly forever.  I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this.

Please see the following example code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ConfigureChartSettings();

        AddFakeData();
    }

    private void AddFakeData()
    {
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2); //Gets plotted at (1,2)
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2); //Gets plotted at (2,2)
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2); //Gets plotted at (3,2)
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2); //Gets plotted at (4,2)
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2); //Gets plotted at (5,2)
    }

    private void ConfigureChartSettings()
    {
        //Set point chart type
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

        //Set the market size
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerSize = 5;

        //Set the marker shape to a circle
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;

        //X and Y values are both between -10 and 10 so set the x and y axes accordingly
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = -10.0;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = 10.0;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = -10.0;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 10.0;

        //Set the titles of the X and Y axes
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "XSignalName";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "YSignalName";

        //Set the Intervals of the X and Y axes, 
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 5;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 5;

        //Set the MajorGrid interval to 5.
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 5;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 5;

        //Set the MinorGrid interval to 1.
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;

        //Set the MinorGrid style to Dot so that it is less obstructive.
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;

        //Enable the minor grids.
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I've already wasted a bunch of time trying to figure out why this could happen and I'm sure it is something incredibly simple but I can't seem to find the answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Dominique, it won't let me add a comment to your comment so I'll add it here.  I just tried this and it seems to solve the problem.  Thanks!  I thought about trying to do something like this yesterday but it really seemed a bit hacky.  I was hoping there would be another way to tell MSChart to stop being so "smart" but this looks like it will work.

Comment: Ok, I spoke too soon.  Upon further testing this doesn't actually solve the problem.  With the way I have this working I only want to store the last X points on the graph, for example purposes lets say X=5.  When Points.Count >= 5 I call Points.RemoveAt(0) before adding a new point.  If I then plot 5 points in a row with an x-axis value of 0 the problem shows up again.  Does anyone know if there is a property to simply tell MsChart to stop trying to be "smart".  It would be so much cleaner than trying to always keep an Empty point on the graph that doesn't have an x-axis value of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case MsChart is trying to be too helpful. It detects you have inserted data points with identical `X == 0` and so auto-magically switch to using the point index as X value. Note that it only happens if X is 0.

You can fix it by adding an extra empty point with a `X != 0`. So adding this at the start of your data entry will give you the plot you want.

```
// insert an empty point with X != 0
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10, 10);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].IsEmpty = true;
// add your points as normal
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2);
```