# C# MSCHART data not plotted correctly on same x-axis

Tags: c#, mschart

Consider the following where the x value is all 0:

```
Series series = chart_RawData_IVCurve.Series.Add("Total Income");
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Points.AddXY(0, 10);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 20);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 30);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 40);
```

The chart rendered wrongly with data plotted as below:
[image]

Strangely if I change the code like below, the chart plotted correctly as intended:

```
Series series = chart_RawData_IVCurve.Series.Add("Total Income");
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Points.AddXY(0, 10);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 20);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 30);
series.Points.AddXY(1, 40);
```

[image]

This happens when all x-axis value = 0, the chart is not plotted correctly. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: This helps! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094162/x-axis-value-increments-automatically-when-first-point-plotted-is-at-0-0-using?rq=2